# NaN produced from Cohen Kappa without 100% agreement

Tags: r, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

Considering the following data frame called `coris_d0`:

```
structure(list(RDT = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    ELISA = c(1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1)), .Names = c("RDT", 
"ELISA"), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to check the agreement between the two methods (RDT and ELISA), so I am carrying out a Cohen Kappa from the `psych` package. If I run the following commands:

```
library("psych")
kappa2(coris_d0)
```

I wil get the following:

```
 Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: unweighted)

 Subjects = 28 
   Raters = 2 
    Kappa = 0 

        z = NaN 
  p-value = NaN
```

This question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157832/cohens-kappa-using-irr-and-kappa2-outputs-nan) is quite similar and I agree with the explanation. However, having a quick look at my data set we can see that **there is no 100% agreement**, so I do not understand why I am getting this "error message".

I don't think the "NAs" are upsetting the code because if I run the same command on the following data frame (which also contains NAs):

```
 structure(list(RDT = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1, 1), ELISA = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("RDT", "ELISA"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I will get:

```
 Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: unweighted)

 Subjects = 7 
   Raters = 2 
    Kappa = 0.588 

        z = 1.71 
  p-value = 0.0877
```

Moreover, we can see that the NA was removed from the analysis.

Comment: Just a quick remark `kappa2` is a function of the `irr` package, not `psych` (which has a function called `cohen.kappa`). I had the same problem as you and tested different packages as well :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because my two "raters" should have at least two levels, which was not an error message from the `kappa2` function.
If I run the following command:

```
library(fmsb)
Kappa.test(x = rep(1,33), y = c(rep(1,3),0,NA,1,NA,rep(1,6),0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,NA,rep(1,3),0,NA,1,1,0,1,NA,1))
```

I will have the following error message:

```
Error in Kappa.test(x = rep(1, 33), y = c(rep(1, 3), 0, NA, 1, NA, rep(1,  : 
  'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
```

Because one of my raters (x) has only one level ("1").